# What does the Lively Medical Alert Watch Monitor?

Tags: sensors, monitoring, lively-medical-alert

According to [MakeUseOf.com](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/internet-things-10-useful-products-must-try-2016/), the Lively Medical Alert Watch...

> ... allows remote health monitoring of your loved ones. The smartwatch can track steps taken as well as other kinds of daily activities, plus it provides an emergency assist button that alerts Lively to call in and check that everything is alright.

What does it actually monitor?  Specifically I would like to know, does it check the vulnerable person's pulse or neural activity, or is it just checking for various motions/actions throughout the day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***What does it actually monitor?***

From the company's web site:

> Lively pillbox activity sensors monitor daily medication activity and
>        create an alert whenever anything is missed

They also have a web based dashboard, which relatives or carers can check.

> Lively's safety watch features a pedometer to keep track of steps throughout
>       the day.

> Coming soon!
>       Clip for auto fall detection

> Turn on/off vibration for reminders, alerts
>       Turn on/off medication reminders

From a USA Today review

> When you're out of range, the watch reminds the person to call 911

***Specifically I would like to know, does it check the vulnerable
person's pulse or neural activity, or is it just checking for various
motions/actions throughout the day?***

> How do we measure daily activity patterns?
>
> - Medication
>
> Attach a sensor to any pillbox to keep track of when medication is taken.
>
> - Food & Drink
>
> Attach a sensor to the refrigerator and other kitchen objects to infer 
>   when food is prepared or consumed.
>
> - Custom
>
> Attach a sensor to a movable object that is part of the daily routine
>   patterns of older adults to log more detail (e.g., bathroom door 
>   or favorite chair) in order to log more detail.

To answer your question:

from the [USA Today article](http://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/columnist/baig/2015/02/05/review-lively-safety-watch-isnt-perfect-but-it-could-save-a-life/22925659/):

> It doesn't monitor sleep or measure heart rate or other vitals.
>        The step counter isn't the most accurate. What is being measured is 
>        the movement of the watch, so my steps tally climbed even when I lay in bed.

Also, Googling for `+"Lively Medical Alert Watch"  +pulse` returned zero hits.

When the company says

> ***infer*** when food is prepared or consumed

it doesn't fill me with confidence.

I also quibble with "keep track of when medication is taken", and say that they can ***infer*** that pills have been taken form a pill box, but not that they have been ingested.

Does this answer your question? It took me 5 minutes Googling, although, in your place, I would have emailed the manufacturer directly.